# help simplifying this boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

xyz’+x’yz+xyz+x’yz’ I have to simplify this expression and return the results in products of sums form in one literal. If I simplify as sum of products I can get y as the answer or one literal but not sure how to express it in product of sums form

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [how to ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.

Comment: Hint: assuming that `'` means boolean negation, you may factorize $yz$ in the two middle parcels of the sum and you may factorize $yz'$ in the left and right terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y$ *is* a product of sums! It is the product of one term, $y$, which is the sum of one literal, $y$

Likewise, it is also a sum of products.

Comment: That makes so much more sense! I had n problems factoring the expression and that was honestly holding me up for hours. Thanks so much!